# How to instantiate base class with different generic types?

Tags: java, android, generics, kotlin

I am trying to create a 2nd constructor and call the parent class with a different generic type based on the constructor invocation. 
1 type is GroupTrackInfoDTO and the other one is TrackInfoDTO but I keep getting a compiling error

> Platform declaration clash: The following declarations have the same
>   JVM signature

My code:

```
class GetSettingsTask
: BizOperationTask {

private var mCallback: BizTaskCallback<TrackSettings>? = null

constructor(operation: BizOperation<GroupTrackInfoDTO>,  mCallback: BizTaskCallback<TrackSettings>) : super(operation) {
    this.mCallback = mCallback
}


constructor(o: BizOperation<TrackInfoDTO>, mCallback: BizTaskCallback<TrackSettings>) : super(o) {
    this.mCallback = mCallback
}
```

if I add a dummy parameter to one of the constructors it worked but no idea why

```
constructor(o: BizOperation<TrackInfoDTO>, mCallback: BizTaskCallback<TrackSettings>, i: Int = 0) : super(o) {
        this.mCallback = mCallback
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

They are the same JVM signature. You can define an abstract class (`AbstractTrackInfoDTO`) that is the parent of `TrackInfoDTO` and `GroupTrackInfoDTO` then declare the constructor as below:

```
constructor(operation: BizOperation<AbstractTrackInfoDTO>,  mCallback: BizTaskCallback<TrackSettings>) : super(operation) {
    this.mCallback = mCallback
}
```